# Why enums have names in C?

Tags: c, enums, c89

Let's take the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>


enum fruit  {APPLE, ORANGE, BANANA};
enum planet {EARTH, MARS, NEPTUNE};


void foo(enum fruit f)
{
    printf("%ld", f);
}


int main()
{
    enum planet p = MARS;

    foo(p); /* compiler doesn't complain */

    return 0;
}
```

What's the point of `enum`s having names, if that code would compile?
Here is my command line for gcc:

```
gcc file.c -ansi -Wall -Wextra
```

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. But your code invokes undefined behaviour and any halfway recent compiler/library should warn for a wrong conversion type specifier in `printf`. And why do you return an error from your main?

Comment: In C enumerations are basically just symbolic integer constants. However, using the wrong enumeration type is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: @Olaf what specifier should I use? (I changed 1 to 0 in the return value of the main function)

Comment: @BiteBytes: In case your questions are not some kind of trolling attempt, you are in urgent need of a good C book and learn how to use google or another search provider of your choice. Almost all your question are covered by basic chapters of a textbook.

Comment: The reason the compiler does not complain, is not because of the function call, which is correct, but because `long` is the same size as `int` on your system, and an `enum` value has type `int`. If you add a a second parameter, and print both, they will work, even though the behaviour was undefined. But if `long` is larger than `int`, as it may be, you'll possibly get compiler warning, and definite wrong result.

Comment: @WeatherVane  would you please show me how to print an `enum` using `printf`, and what's wrong with the `ld` specifier?

Comment: With the `%d` format specifier, as an `enum` value is of type `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It is completely irrelevant if `long` has the same size as `int`. It has a higher rank, and is a different type.

Comment: [Some helpful warnings](https://pastebin.com/maFBuGmy).

Comment: @WhozCraig but all that the standard says about enum is that is an integral, not an int.

Comment: @Olaf I did say it is undefined behaviour, but happened to work if they are the same size.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I refer to "The reason the compiler does not complain, is not because of the function call, which is correct, but because long is the same size as int on your system" in your comment. The reason it does not complain might be the warning is not enabled. After all there is no requirement for the compiler to emit a dignostic message at all. But tbh, I suspect this is another trolling attempt.

Comment: @Olaf that is why I wrote "you'll **possibly** get compiler warning"

Comment: @Olaf are there any more options I can use besides `-Wall -Wextra` with gcc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, in C99, the "tag" (what you call the name, e.g. `fruit`) of `enum`  is optional.

So

```
enum { BLACK, RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW, WHITE };
```

is acceptable (and quite useful)

and you can even give values integral constants

```
enum { RFCHTTP =2068, RFCSMTP= 821 };
```

which is a more modern way than

```
#define RFCHTTP 2068
#define RFCSMTP 821
```

(in particular, such `enum` values are known to the debugger, when you compile with debug info)

But in C `enum`  are mostly integral values. Things are different in C++.

Regarding using `%ld` format control conversion for `printf` with an `enum` argument it is probably some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (so you should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108)). Probably `gcc -Wall -Wextra` might warn you.

BTW, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) has many options. Read its chapter on [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

I recommend (in 2017) coding for [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)), not old 1989 ANSI C.

Comment: Thank's for you answer, first I'm compiling with the option `-ansi`, which restrict my code to C89 (see the tag). Second I have this question: "why should I use `%d` specifer to print an `enum`"? cause `%d` is used to print integers, and enums are of integral types and not necessarily integers, wouldn't be more appropriate to use the `%ld`?

Comment: I believe that using a 1989 standard in 2017 is unreasonable for a language with both 1999 and 2011 standards (and both being better than the ANSI one)

Comment: I'm not using it, I'm just trying to learn as possible as I could about it, before I move on, because it doesn't make sense to praise K&R book everywhere then tell people stay away from that version of C

Comment: And please, if you could, I'm still waiting for an answer to the question about the specifier.

Answer (score 3):

Even if your code will compile, the following will not

```
enum fruit *f = 0;
enum planet *p = f;
```

since `enum fruit` and `enum planet` are two different unrelated types.

What you observe in your code sample is a mere *implicit conversion* between two enum types in value context. In exactly the same way you can implicitly convert a `double` value to `int` type. Yet, I hope, you will not use that to conclude that there's no reason to distinguish between `double` and `int`.

Your question would be more justified if you asked "Why do we have implicit conversions between unrelated enum types?" As for enum types having distinctive names... there are perfectly good reasons for that.